# Group of order $pm$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $pm$, where $p$ is a prime not dividing $m$, and let $P\in Syl_p(G)$. If $N_G(P)=P$, show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $m$.

The original problem has another condition assuming $G$ is solvable. I think I am able to prove it in this case. However, I think the proposition should be true without the restriction of $G$. All I need ro do is to find $G$ contains a subgroup of order  $m$, I can show that if this kind of subgroup exists it must be normal. But I am not able to find the $m$ ordered group.

Comment: This follows from Burnside's Transfer Theorem. I don't know of any other proof.

Comment: I deleted my comment. I had somehow missed the fact that the prime was assumed to only divide the order once.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. Now I have figured it out. Even if I don't wanna use Burnside's directly, I somehow have to apply focal subgroup theorem.

Comment: Yes you can do it that way. Porve that the focal subgroup is trivial, which shows that $P \cap [G,G] = 1$.